# How can you manually bypass admin access (or gain it) and add a program to startup?

Tags: malware, keyloggers

I was looking into keyloggers and wanted to understand how does someone get a keylogger to run every time the target computer is active (obviously a program that targets this purpose, but an explanation would help)? I want to know how is this possible and how to do this (for testing purposes).

Answer (score 2):

The concept you are looking for is called "persistence".

There are a few ways for this to happen:

- infect a common program that is frequently run by users (like the browser)
- loading the malware into the Scheduled Tasks or crontab so that it runs after the operating system boots
- infecting or replacing a core system file that gets executed on boot
- infecting the firmware of the system so that it is run before the operating system boots

As for "bypassing admin", that's a different topic entirely. Depending on what kind of persistence we are talking about:

- admin is not needed to infect user-level programs
- many users run with admin privileges, so there is no "by-pass" involved
- some malware tries to convince the user to enable admin-level privileges
- vulnerabilities in the operating system or user-level programs could be exploited to grant the malware admin or even system-level permissions